# Coloured textures for POIs

Tags: skmaps, scoutstyleeditor

I was trying to use a coloured texture (PNG 24/RGB) for a POI (bicycle_parking) and it was not being rendered. It was added properly as a texture, it just won't be rendered on the POI.

After some testing I came to believe that POIs only accept grayscale textures that can later be filled up with a color. **Is this right?**

I also found out that the icon needs to be of a specific size (I got it working only at 32x32 pixels and 512x512, but the scaling did not make it look good). **Is there any information regarding this?**

Now I have a grayscale icon (mostly white) but the fill color does not change the white as expected. This is as far as I got..

Here's a set of icons similar to the ones I need to render into POIs

[image: Sample icons]

How could I achieve adding this type of icons as the texture of a POI? Workarounds/hacks are welcome as well :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The texture of the Poi must have a size that is a power of 2 and goes from 32x32 up until 512x512. Also make sure that the colour code of that image is RGB anything else wont work. For the best visual result you have to create 3 sets of pngs for different screen densities, for example see heatmap_legend.png then look at heatmap_legend@2x.png and heatmap_legend@3x.png, you can find them in the "common" folder.

Answer (score 2):

So turns out that the color wasn't a problem after all. It was quite tricky to get one image working, but once I had the image working, adding color to it and saving the PNG worked just fine.

The problem with the image size I experienced is still happening. You need to export it in 32x32, 64x64 or 96x96 in order to StyleEditor not to crash when opening the file.